# Changing text input using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function so that when one of my buttons is pressed the value of the text input changes to the value of the button pressed.

```
<div id="viewer">
<h1>
<input type="text" id="Screen" maxlength="8" value="0"/>
</h1>

<h2>
<button type="button" value="1" id="1">1</button>
<button type="button" value="2" id="2">2</button>
</h2>
</div>
```

This is the function I am trying to use but am going wrong somewhere:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function(){

   var $val = $("#Display").val();
    alert($val);
       onclick="sevenClick()";

});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var test = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#Screen').val(test);
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry i had to edit it a couple of times, some typing mistakes, try it it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you changed an ID and need to change a few other things

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {

    var val = $(this).val()
    $("#Screen").val(val);
    alert(val);
    onclick = "sevenClick()";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewer">
<h1>
<input type="text" id="Screen" maxlength="8" value="0"/>
</h1>

<h2>
<button type="button" value="1" id="1">1</button>
<button type="button" value="2" id="2">2</button>
</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to keep the actual button value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var $val = $(this).val();
    //alert($val);
    $('#Screen').val($val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewer">
  <h1>
<input type="text" id="Screen" maxlength="8" value="0"/>
</h1>

  <h2>
<button type="button" value="1" id="1">1</button>
<button type="button" value="2" id="2">2</button>
</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the value of button and set it to the input box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var butVal = $(this).val(); //get current button value here 
        $("#Screen").text(butVal); // set button value to the textbox
    });
});
```